# as much memory {as / as is } absolutely necessary

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions

Example:

> Explicit variable declaration speeds up the execution of your procedure. Since Visual Basic knows the data type, it reserves only as much memory **as is** absolutely necessary to store the data.

If I got rid of **is** and rewrote that sentence like this:

> Explicit variable declaration speeds up the execution of your procedure. Since Visual Basic knows the data type, it reserves only as much memory **as** absolutely necessary to store the data.

Would the sentence be still grammatically correct and equivalent in meaning to the original one? If so, why then did the author who wrote that sentence opt for including **is**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct and don't give place to misunderstandings. Both sound fine to me, but if I had to say it, I'd go with just *as*; but that's personal preference or habit.

Why did the author use *as is*? Since both are correct, probably just a matter of preference, too.